# x:Bind call function with params object[] and pass n parameters

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui

Is it possible to call a helper function in XAML that takes any number of parameters using x:Bind? I have this XAML code:

```
<Button Content="Button content"
          Margin="0,0,10,0"
          Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
          IsEnabled="{x:Bind helpers:CommonHelpers.TrueForAll(ViewModel.Property,ViewModel.SomeOtherProperty)}"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"> 
</Button>
```

where the TrueForAll function looks like this:

`public static bool TrueForAll(params object[] objects) => objects.All(x => x != null);`

When trying to use this in action with multiple parameters, the compiler says `Cannot find a function overload that takes 2 parameters.` and when only using one, it expects object[] so it says `Expected argument of type 'Object[]', but found 'MyType'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a helper function in XAML that takes any number of parameters using x:Bind?

No.

The solution is to define the method with explicit parameters:

```
public static bool TrueForAll(IEnumerable<object> objects) 
    => objects?.All(x => x != null) == true;
```

And create the parameter programmatically:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Input => 
    new object[] { ViewModel.Property, ViewModel.SomeOtherProperty };
```

XAML is a *markup* language and trying to do things like creating arrays in it is an anti-pattern really. You should create the input parameter in the code-behind of the very same view or move your logic to the view model.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is related to the **params** keyword. [x:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) can't recognize `params` that you defined. It is still looking for method with explicit parameter lists.

My suggestion is that you might need to use `List<object>` or `ObservableCollection<object>` as the parameter for the method. And create such a property in your ViewModel as well. This could be accepted by the **x:Bind**.